# Character "%1$d", "%1$s" getting split in Arabic text

Tags: android, xml, arabic, arabic-support

I am tasked with translating an English file to Arabic. Which I did in Notepad++. However when sending the file to the remote client said that lines with these characters cannot be separated. "%1$d",  "%1$s"

I have tried copying the entire text to Microsoft word and making it so it would display text from right to left. But whenever I enter the Arabic lines the "%" skips and everything gets disorganized. When I attempt to delete the characters it deletes everything but the said character!

> انتهت ( تابع المهمة بعد %1$d ثواني)

Any clue on how to work with these characters?

Comment: Why are you sending this in word?  If it came in an an xml file (which I assume it did, %1$d is a variable that will be replaced by a number at runtime), give them an xml file back.

Comment: I did give them an xml file back. What I meant is that even when parsed in word it's the same thing.

Comment: The %1$d will be replaced at runtime with the proper value.  Don't touch that.  Just put it right in the text as is.  It will work right in the end when they use the proper version of getString.

Answer (score 0):

I think when the client uses this code line in file XML it's will work

```
<string name="finsish_task">انتهت ( تابع المهمة بعد %1$d ثواني)</string>
```

Comment: It doesn't. That's why they sent a document with lines needing edit.